# How to grow/shrink a selection per tab?

Tags: key-bindings, selection, nvim

How to have a selection grow/shrink as we tabulate, regardless of cursor position ? The selection can span more than one line. Kind of like this:

[image]

For the tabbing I've got this part so far:

```
xnoremap <TAB> >gv
xnoremap <S-TAB> <gv
```

Just need the logic of the growing/shrinking selection. Anyone have some suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works if you're in Visual Line mode, so one option (the one I'd recommend) is to always convert to Visual mode (from character or block visual mode) if needed, before the operation.

With characterwise visual mode, the `>` command affects the line in a way that the original bounds of the selection are lost (in that they're no longer tied to the characters that were now shifted), so restoring the selection makes less sense in that case. (You could try to compensate for that by calculating the adjusted column after the shift, but that's way too complex of an approach.)

Converting to Visual Line mode first:

```
xnoremap <expr> <Tab> (mode() ==# 'V' ? '' : 'V') . '>gv'
xnoremap <expr> <S-Tab> (mode() ==# 'V' ? '' : 'V') . '<gv'
```

If you want the mappings to support both Visual *and* Select mode, then all you need is to use `vnoremap` instead. This works because when a `vnoremap` mapping is executed in Select mode, the selection is first converted to Visual mode and the mapping is executed in Visual mode. The Visual selection at the end is automatically converted back to Select mode at the end. So you do get the implicit conversion to Select Line mode when using a different kind of selection, but the mappings do work.

```
vnoremap <expr> <Tab> (mode() ==# 'V' ? '' : 'V') . '>gv'
vnoremap <expr> <S-Tab> (mode() ==# 'V' ? '' : 'V') . '<gv'
```

Comment: @Akharrou Using `vnoremap` here works for both Visual and Select mode. I updated the answer to cover that case too.

Answer (score 1):

If it’s always a whole line, just replace `gv` with `V`

We tried

```
xnoremap <expr> <Tab> line("'<") isnot# line("'>") ? '>gvVgv' : '>V'
```

to handle multi-line selections and single-line selections, but there are some issues (see comments)

Comment: @Akharrou perhaps gvV then?

Comment: Hm, maybe you could use `line('<') isnot# line('>')`? @Akharrou

Comment: Ah, try `line("'<")` and similar. See `:help line`, `:help '<`

Comment: You have to change both < and > to use the mark syntax...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116528/discussion-between-d-ben-knoble-and-akharrou).